# Generate dynamic row everytime while focusing on last row element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one table. When I focus on last row element, I want to copy last row of table and append it at last position. This I can do it as per my code.

Now, this new row become my last row. After this I am unable to generate row on clicking of its element. Infact it generates row on clicking of previous row(which one is last previously).

How can I achieve it?

```js
$('.ankita').focus(function(){  

  var $tr    = $(this).closest('.trbar');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);

$(this).removeClass("ankita");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='tbl'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Cell1</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Cell2</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="trbar">
            <td>
                <p>Cell3</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="" class="ankita" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create a delegate event listener, which will only react to the focus events from the last row.

```js
$('#tbl').on('focus', 'tr:last .ankita', function(){  

  var $tr    = $(this).closest('.trbar');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);

$(this).removeClass("ankita");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='tbl'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Cell1</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Cell2</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="trbar">
            <td>
                <p>Cell3</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="" class="ankita" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: we don't need to remove class if we using the delegation way, because we are delegating to last tr always

Comment: @SandeepSaroha true, that's just remaining logic from the initial OP runnable snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Ankita, you are just missing param of clone method

var $clone = $tr.clone(true);

this param Specifies that event handlers in clone obj also will be copied.

```js
$('#tbl').on('focus', 'tr:last .ankita', function(){  

  var $tr    = $(this).closest('.trbar');
    var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);

$(this).removeClass("ankita");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='tbl'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Cell1</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Cell2</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="trbar">
            <td>
                <p>Cell3</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="" class="ankita" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Given that the event listener is on the table, what events are being cloned?

Comment: @taplar, in the initial code there is no listener on the table. Listener is on the input which is part of clone obj.

Comment: Right, but my solution, and your solution have it on the table.  So while clone(true) does what you say it does, it's not necessary

Comment: @taplar, what said is true for the clone obj and Table was not part of clone obj :) I added the context  in the answer as well

Comment: Both approach have it own value,
- Delegation one is more clean 
- Mine have minimal changes

Comment: Your answer is also using delegation.  It has the added change of clone(true) on the tr, which will clone event handlers on the tr, which are not specified in the original question to be existing at all.